# Swift Can't unwrap optional

Tags: swift, option-type

> Given a pattern and a string str, find if str follows the same
>   pattern.
>
> Here follow means a full match, such that there is a bijection between
>   a letter in pattern and a non-empty word in str.
>
> Examples: pattern = "abba", str = "dog cat cat dog" should return
>   true.
>
> pattern = "abba", str = "dog cat cat fish" should return false.
>
> pattern = "aaaa", str = "dog cat cat dog" should return false.
>
> pattern = "abba", str = "dog dog dog dog" should return false.
>
> Notes: You may assume pattern contains only lowercase letters, and str
>   contains lowercase letters separated by a single space.

```
class Solution
{
    func wordPattern(pattern: String, _ str: String) -> Bool
    {

        let arr = str.characters.split{$0 == " "}.map(String.init)
        if arr.count != pattern.characters.count
        {
            return false
        }

        var dict = [Character:String]()

        for i in (0...arr.count-1)
        {
            let cha = pattern[pattern.startIndex.advancedBy(i)]

            if dict.keys.contains(cha)
            {
                if dict[cha]! != arr[i]
                {
                    return false
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if dict.values.contains(dict[cha]!)
                //fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
                {
                    return false
                }

                dict[cha] = arr[i]
            }

        }
        return true
    }
}


var test = Solution()
var result = test.wordPattern("abba", "dog cat cat dog")
print(result)
```

> I do not know "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an
>   Optional value". Any help, I appreciate it. Thank you so much!

Comment: I do not know what your question mean? Do you have any idea how to fix it? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Revise your conditions.

Your `else` branch is executed when `dict.keys.contains(cha)` is `false`, in other words, when the dictionary does not contain `cha`. You then try to access `dict[cha]` which you already know must return `nil` (because `cha` is not in the dictionary). And then you try to unwrap it. Unwrapping `nil` crashes your app.

Also consider that the condition is trying to check whether a value taken from the dictionary is contained in the dictionary. What are you trying to do?

All you want is probably just (note there are no nasty `!`):

```
let arrayValue = arr[i]

if let value = dict[cha] {
    if value != arrayValue {
        return false
    }
} else {
    if dict.values.contains(arrayValue) { // maybe this? it's hard to guess
        return false
    }

    dict[cha] = arrayValue
}
```

Comment: Nice. It works. Thank you so much!